# Safely copy all files from occasionally-failing external drive?

Tags: backup, hard-drive, filesystems

I have an external hard drive which is clearly on its last legs. I get that “beep”-like sound when I disconnect it, and once I head a soft click sound. However, I have it read-only mounted on my Mac and can typically copy anywhere from 5-50 GB off of it before it hangs and I have to stop and try again. Failure is never in the same place twice.

My goal is to get every single file copied off — there are about 200k of them. A whole drive image fails, rsync hangs, etc.

I have a full list of files on the drive (incl their sizes in bytes). My thought was to write a quick script that cycles thru that list, and for each file, see if it exists in my backup folder with the same size; if so, skip; if not, use `cp` to copy the file. Repeat over and over until no files need to be copied.

Is there a better/safer/smarter way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

After doing more research, it seems like the best option is to use GNU `ddrescue`, which incrementally creates a disk image of the drive, skipping bad areas and returning to them after the full disk has been processed... Going to give that a try and report back here with results.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using rsync, as it will help copy whatever is missing

rsync -av /path/to/src-drive /path/to/destination-copy

Then repeat after every fail when the drive is online, and it will continue where it left off.

Comment: I tried that first, and it seemed to just hang eventually...

Comment: @DanM you can try `--ignore-errors` option for `rsync`

Comment: @AlexD did that as well — same thing. Is there a way to set the timeout when a particular file operation fails?

Comment: If you have the drive on a SATA port, you can try recoverdisk mentioned below. It works horrible on USB-mass-storage devices however.

https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=recoverdisk&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+7.1-RELEASE&format=html

I've used that a couple of times with great results. The output is a disk image with as much info as possible retrieved, and you could mount it directely. If there's low level problems, it's the fastest way to get around them. If you don't get everything off, you can use a recovery tool on the image, which will be fast as it does not IO-hang.

Comment: @Martin alas, it's a USB drive -- a Western Digital "My Passport". Which, unfortunately, speaks only USB (i.e. I couldn't remove it from its enclosure and connect it to a SATA drive).